# ASP.Net Core Web API implementation with OData fails for a single entity URI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, odata

No matter what I try, I cannot get OData 7.3.0 to return a single resource using a simple URL like `https://localhost:44316/odata/Widget(5)`...

Steps to reproduce:

1. I created a database called 'WidgetDB' is SQL Server.
2. I used the following SQL script to add a single table with some data:

```sql
create table widget
(
   widget_id int identity(1, 1) not null,
   widget_name varchar(100) not null,
   constraint PK_widget primary key clustered (widget_id)
)
GO

insert into widget (widget_name) 
values
('Thingamabob'), ('Thingamajig'), ('Thingy'),
('Doomaflotchie'), ('Doohickey'), ('Doojigger'), ('Doodad'),
('Whatchamacallit'), ('Whatnot'), ('Whatsit'),
('Gizmo'), ('Nicknack')
GO
```

3. In Visual Studio 2019, I created a new Web API solution using ASP.Net Core 3.1 called "WidgetWebAPI".
4. I added Nuget Packages for the following:

   - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.3
   - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.1.3
   - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 3.1.3
   - Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 3.1.3
   - Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.4.0
5. I removed the Weatherforecast.cs class and WeatherforecastController.cs classes from the default scaffold project that is created by Visual Studio.
6. I went to the package manager console and typed in the following line to scaffold a DbContext for Entity Framework core:

   ```
   PM> Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Server=.;Database=WidgetDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
   Build started...
   Build succeeded.
   PM>
   ```
7. I opened the **appsettings.json** file and added a `ConnectionStrings` section:

```js
{
 "ConnectionStrings": {
   "Default": "Server=.;Database=WidgetDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"
 },
 "Logging": {
   "LogLevel": {
     "Default": "Information",
     "Microsoft": "Warning",
     "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
   }
 },
 "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

8. I opened the Models\WidgetDBContext.cs file that step 6 created, and took out the `OnConfiguring` method:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WidgetWebAPI.Models
{
   public partial class WidgetDBContext : DbContext
   {
       public WidgetDBContext() { }
       public WidgetDBContext(DbContextOptions<WidgetDBContext> options) : base(options) { }
       public virtual DbSet<Widget> Widget { get; set; }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           modelBuilder.Entity<Widget>(entity =>
           {
               entity.ToTable("widget");
               entity.Property(e => e.WidgetId).HasColumnName("widget_id");
               entity.Property(e => e.WidgetName)
                   .IsRequired()
                   .HasColumnName("widget_name")
                   .HasMaxLength(100)
                   .IsUnicode(false);
           });

           OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
       }

       partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
   }
}
```

9. I opened the Startup.cs file, and piecing together what complete examples I could find, I cleaned up the code to the following:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;
using WidgetWebAPI.Models;

namespace WidgetWebAPI
{
   public class Startup
   {
       public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
       {
           Configuration = configuration;
       }

       public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

       // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           // See note on https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/experimenting-with-odata-in-asp-net-core-3-1/
           // Disabling end-point routing isn't ideal, but is required for the current implementation of OData 
           // (7.4.0 as of this comment).  As OData is further updated, this will change.
           //services.AddControllers();
           services.AddControllers(mvcOoptions => mvcOoptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

           services.AddDbContext<Models.WidgetDBContext>(optionsBuilder =>
           {
               if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
               {
                   optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
               }
           });

           services.AddOData();
       }

       // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
       {
           if (env.IsDevelopment())
           {
               app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
           }

           app.UseHttpsRedirection();
           app.UseRouting();
           app.UseAuthorization();

           // Again, this is temporary due to current OData implementation.  See note above.
           //app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
           //{
           //    endpoints.MapControllers();
           //});

           app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
           {
               routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
           });
       }

       private IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
       {
           var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
           builder.Namespace = "WidgetData";   // Hide Model Schema from $metadata
           builder.EntitySet<Widget>("Widgets").EntityType
               .HasKey(r => r.WidgetId)
               .Filter()   // Allow for the $filter Command
               .Count()    // Allow for the $count Command
               .Expand()   // Allow for the $expand Command
               .OrderBy()  // Allow for the $orderby Command
               .Page()     // Allow for the $top and $skip Commands
               .Select();  // Allow for the $select Command;

           return builder.GetEdmModel();
       }
   }
}
```

10. A created the class **Controllers\WidgetsController.cs** by right-clicking on the **Controllers** folder, selecting *Add Controller...*, and choosing the **API Controller with actions, using Entity Framework** option in the wizard dialog:

    [image: Add Controller Dialog]

    ***This was my first mistake.***  See step 13.
11. I added the `[EnableQuery]` attribute to the `GetWidget()` method of the Controller class that the scaffold created, and changed the class inheritance from `ControllerBase` to `ODataController`.  Other than ensuring my namespaces were properly resolved, I did nothing else to the existing file.
12. I changed the debug settings to set the URL to *odata/Widgets* rather than *weatherforecast* and ran the application.

***NOTHING WORKED!***
After hours of cursing and puzzlement and trial and error, I finally figured out that by default OData hates plural named objects and controllers.

13. (Or 9 revisted) I went back into my Startup.cs class and changed this line of code to use the singular form:

```cs
builder.EntitySet<Widget>("Widget").EntityType
```

14. (Or 10 revisted) I ran the *Add Controller...* wizard again and this time, I set the Controller Name to `WidgetController`, and then reapplied the changes mentioned in step 11.
15. I updated the Launch Browser Debug setting in the project properties to *odata/Widget* and ran the application again:

***All the widgets are returned, so we've made progress!***

However, any attempt to get a single entity using a well-formed OData Url such as `https://localhost:44316/odata/Widget(4)` simply returns the whole data set rather than the single entity whose Id is 4.  In fact, a SQL Profiler trace shows that the constructed SQL query doesn't contain anything other than a select from the entire table:

```sql
SELECT [w].[widget_id], [w].[widget_name]
FROM [widget] AS [w]
```

I have looked all over the Internet and my Google Fu is failing me. I cannot find a reason this isn't working, nor a current example demonstrating where it *is* working and what I am missing!  I can find many examples demonstrating $filter, $expand, etc.  but not a single example of just returning a single entity from a set.

I've tried things like changing the method signatures.  This has no effect either:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<Widget> GetWidget() => _context.Widget.AsQueryable();

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<Widget> GetWidget([FromODataUri] int id) => _context.Widget.Where(r => r.WidgetId == id);
```

I know the end-point is *capable* of returning a single entity.  I can get it to do so by entering the URL: `https://localhost:44316/odata/Widget?$filter=WidgetId eq 5`, which works fine and appropriately causes the correct SQL to be generated against the database.

Comment: I shared the demo project at https://github.com/mitselplik/widget-web-api as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After three days of frustration, I stumbled across the solution to the problem - a solution that is maddening in its simplicity, and infuriating that it doesn't appear to be documented anywhere as a critical necessity in any examples I can find.

When it comes to the method signature for a single entity, this method signature doesn't work.  The routing middleware never matches to it, so the method never gets called:

```cs
 [EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("({id})", RouteName = nameof(GetWidget))]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetWidget([FromODataUri] int id)
{
    var widget = await _context.Widget.FindAsync(id);
    if (widget == null) return NotFound();
    return Ok(widget);
}
```

Either of the following options works fine however:

```
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetWidget([FromODataUri] int key)
{
     var widget = await _context.Widget.FindAsync(key);
     if (widget == null) return NotFound();
     return Ok(widget);
}

[EnableQuery]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetWidget([FromODataUri] int keyWidgetId)
{
     var widget = await _context.Widget.FindAsync(keyWidgetId);
     if (widget == null) return NotFound();
     return Ok(widget);
}
```

The key to the mystery (pun intended) is using the word `key` for the id...

Why isn't this written somewhere in giant bold type?  So stupid... #fumes #aggravation

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. I cloned your repo but also could not get it working. Now that you've posted this, I notice that the parameter is named `key` in this documentation as well: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/asp-net-core-odata-now-available/

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

In your `Startup.cs`:

```cs
app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
{
    // the following will not work as expected
    // BUG: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1837
    // routeBuilder.SetDefaultODataOptions(new ODataOptions { UrlKeyDelimiter = Microsoft.OData.ODataUrlKeyDelimiter.Parentheses });
    var options = routeBuilder.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ODataOptions>();
    options.UrlKeyDelimiter = Microsoft.OData.ODataUrlKeyDelimiter.Parentheses;
    routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
});
```

At the top of your controller, add:

```cs
[ODataRoutePrefix("Widget")]
```

Remove the `[EnableQuery]` attribute if you want to retrieve a single entity. Instead, use:

```cs
[ODataRoute("({id})", RouteName = nameof(GetWidget))]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetWidget([FromODataUri] int id)
{
    var widget = await _context.Widget.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.WidgetId == id);
    return Ok(widget);
}
```

You also don't need the `[HttpGet("{id}")]` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt to help :-)  None of the above works however.  I have added the solution to github @ https://github.com/mitselplik/widget-web-api in case you think it might help.

Comment: Also, I don't know exactly how it works in the plumbing, but is it possible that the MVC routing mechanism for attribute routing in superceding the OData routing so that its never getting the chance to do anything?  I tried tracing into the UseMVC(...) call because I noticed the order in the debug variables.  It appears Attribute routing is deliberately inserted it the beginning of RouteBuilder.Routes.

Comment: @Mitselplik Ok I'll clone your repo and check it out. In the meantime, I have a working version deployed if you want to check out how I set it up: https://github.com/crgolden/Inventory